# Is it okay to call finish() directly after invoking Provider methods?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-contentprovider, bulkinsert, activity-finish

Setup: FirstActivity opens SecondActivity, SecondActivity asks user to select images, give them titles; when user is finished they click "Save" button that invokes method saveToDatabase which calls for a bulk insert. The desire is to have the user return to FirstActivity after they click "Save" button.

This is the current setup:

```
private void saveToDatabase() {
    int arraySize = beanList.size();
    ContentValues[] valuesArray = new ContentValues[arraySize];

    ContentValues values;
    String imageuri;
    String title;
    int counter = 0;

    for(Bean b : beanList){
        imageuri = b.getImageUri();
        title = b.getImageTitle();

        values = new ContentValues();           
        values.put(CollectionsTable.COL_NAME, nameOfCollection);
        values.put(CollectionsTable.COL_IMAGEURI, imageuri);
        values.put(CollectionsTable.COL_TITLE, title);
        values.put(CollectionsTable.COL_SEQ, counter +1);

        valuesArray[counter] = values;
        counter++;
    }
    getContentResolver().bulkInsert(CollectionsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, valuesArray);   

    // Does this squash the db/provider call? This is working now but will it always?       
    finish();               
}
```

...and it is working but I have a lingering fear that it may not work all the time. So my question is, is calling `finish()` directly after `getContentResolver().bulk...` an issue? Is there a better way to handle what I'm trying to do (save to database & return user to previous activity in response to one user event)? Thank you. PS: This is my first app, if you see code that should be handled better I'm all ears on that, too.

Comment: It isn't a good practice to work with content providers from UI thread. You should extract all interactions with your content provider to the worker thread or you can have UI glithes if some long running operations will be executed during work with content provider. So when user clicks Save button you can start a new Thread to save all data and immediately call finish() to close the activity. You can read about threads in Android [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads)

Comment: @makovkastar, thank you. I thought because this was a call to a ContentProvider that it would magically occur in another thread, is that wrong? In [this tutorial](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/11/android-database-content-provider.html), in the "CountryEditActivity", their calls to the Provider should have been encased in something like an AsynTask?

Comment: No, you must manually create a new thread, it will not be created automatically after calling the method `getContentResolver().bulkInsert(...)`. Yes, AsynTask is a good way to do work in the separate thread. But the main aim of AsyncTask is to give a posibility to update the UI before starting the work, during execution and after finish. But in your case there is no interactions with UI thread so I don't see a need to use it. But in the case if you want to save your data and only AFTER it has been saved - close the activity - AsyncTask is the best choice.

Comment: Okay. So the "magic" of a ContentProvider + CursorLoader combo is for keeping things like listviews updated off the UI/Worker thread. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html# clearly says queries should be made on another thread. Some tutorials don't do this in their demonstrations: [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#todo), [or this](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/11/android-database-content-provider.html), [or this](http://blog.vladimirvivien.com/2011/11/19/a-pattern-for-creating-custom-android-content-providers/), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the main question was: is it okay to call `finish()` directly after a Provider method call. And given makovkastar's comments, the solution is not to call `finish()` directly after the Provider method call but to instead do something like:

```
private void saveToDatabase() {
    int arraySize = beanList.size();
    final ContentValues[] valuesArray = new ContentValues[arraySize];

    ContentValues values;
    String imageuri;
    String title;
    int counter = 0;

    for(Bean b : beanList){
        imageuri = b.getImageUri();
        title = b.getImageTitle();

        values = new ContentValues();           
        values.put(CollectionsTable.COL_NAME, nameOfCollection);
        values.put(CollectionsTable.COL_IMAGEURI, imageuri);
        values.put(CollectionsTable.COL_TITLE, title);
        values.put(CollectionsTable.COL_SEQ, counter +1);

        valuesArray[counter] = values;
        counter++;
    }

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            getContentResolver().bulkInsert(CollectionsContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, valuesArray);   
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            finish();   
        }           
    };

    task.execute();                 
}
```

This works and now my previous fears are allayed. Thanks, makovkastar.